# Lower the Locked Balance Limit

Tags: transaction-confirmation, balance

It seems like monero cli has a locked balance at 10 blocks.

Is there any way for me to lower that in the software?
Or is on the protocol level that tx's with less than 10 confirmations cannot be spent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, change [this line](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_config.h#L48) and recompile. It's a wallet thing, not consensus.

There are caveats:

- You'll probably be the only one with changed config so someone could use it to fingerprint your TXes
- If a reorg happens, there's the risk of your transaction becoming invalid because inputs are referenced by offset